# Bicycle computers that can transmit audio, music?

Tags: bike-computer

It appears that even the more high end bicycle computer products don't feature music playback.

This is mildly surprising, considering that these high end devices (and probably lower end devices by now) feature a full Bluetooth stack.

Using an off the shelf library for A2DP shouldn't be much work, and would probably require no hardware modifications whatsoever.

Considering this, I'd be surprised that there doesn't exist a product that implements this. Does really no one care to listen to music while riding their bicycles?

Comment: "Does really no one care to listen to music while riding their bicycles?' - I'd say a pretty sizeable majority do not.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: You might want to edit your question to say why this would be a major benefit over either using a phone for everything, or using a phone in a jersey pocket for streaming music

Comment: *Does really no one care to listen to music while riding their bicycles?* Right - not being able to hear someone or something approaching from behind is sooo safe...

Comment: I frequently listen to music, especially on longer solo rides (4/5/6hrs), helps me munch up the miles. Besides, deaf people are able to safely ride bikes, right? Hearing is useful, but not essential for safe riding.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I use a mounted speaker.  I can hear the things approaching from behind and when I approach others from behind they will hear my bell, vocal announcement, and my music.

Answer (score 10):

Disclaimer: I have been working on software for a GPS sports watch, but I have not been involved in product management.

The whole reason for sports watches and bike computers to exist is limited functionality compared to a generic Android device. Limiting functionality to cover only sports allows the software to use less CPU and memory, which in turn saves power both directly and by allowing using smaller processor. This in turn allows using smaller battery, and eventually making the whole device smaller, more durable and maybe more affordable compared to a generic Android device with same sports functionality.

Now, to enable the bike computer to play back music, you'd need to do the following:

- Add larger Flash memory to store the music files. This is cheap and doesn't require power
- Add a way to synchronize the music library (USB and computer-compatible filesystem if you already don't have those, or a proprietary sync protocol and app which cost developer time)
- Add A2DP support. This needs memory, some CPU power and you might need to license the software implementation or do it yourself. Integrating off the shelf libraries into embedded software seems to always be painful, so in the worst case you'll end up evaluating a few off the shelf libraries and finally doing it yourself.
- Add UI for controlling the music. It's not obvious how to do it without making the core UI for exercise more complicated. It will cost memory and developer time, too.

Most cyclist already carry a smart phone that is better equipped to play music than the bike computer will ever be (in addition to stuff like making phone calls or showing maps), so there isn't much to be gained by competing with them.

Comment: It’s honestly embarrassing how *bad* many bicycle computers are compared to even cheap smartphones. If there were even a single good bike computer Android app I’d probably replace my Garmin Edge 820 with a smartphone.

Comment: It's hard to imagine that many people want to fiddle with manually sync'ing music to a bike computer like we used to do with MP3 players circa 2000 when they already likely have a smartphone they already know how to use ready to play their music and/or connected to any streaming service they may use.

Comment: @Michael bike computers and sports watches have some pretty extreme constraints compared to smartphones, and they are niche products so the manufacturers don't have comparable R&D budgets and there's very little off the shelf software available. Everyone's waiting for the moment when it becomes feasible to just take Android Wear and run it in a sports watch or bike head unit, but so far all attempts have fallen short.

Comment: @Micheal. Have you considered the reason there is not 'single good bike computer Andriod App" -  No app, no matter how good, competes with the simplicity of doing one job well and always doing that job well - "Just works"   In my experience, Android based solutions require setup, and either   'Just about work always' , or "Work just about always" - i.e. "Just about works". I admit, my tolerance for faffing about when I want to be riding is exceptionally low.

Comment: @ZachLipton The motivation behind this, is among other things, that a Di2 capable bicycle has buttons integrated into the shifters, that would allow me to switch tracks without the hassle of trying to operate a touch screen. I can operate my Edge 830 like this, but it has zero music support, despite being quite pricey.

Comment: @mattnz Except that a Garmin Edge 830 doesn't even do one thing well. The GPS takes forever to start up compared to a cheap low-end smartphone, the route calculation feature takes 15 seconds to work out a simple course, the temperature sensor is a joke and takes forever to adjust. I could go on.

Comment: Don't buy Garmin then. Another disclaimer, I have never worked for Garmin. As for switching tracks, current smart phones have speech recognition that can be used to switch tracks, and many headsets have tap controls or buttons for the same. Overriding Di2 buttons for it seems bad UX to me.

Comment: @Michael: there is nothing stopping you from using your phone as your bike computer. But the huge sales of non-phone bike computers shows people are seeing things you don't, that are worth paying many hundreds of dollars for. You only think they're bad because you clearly don't understand the constraints they operate in. Try seeing if your phone can do the job for 24 hours without being charged, my Garmin 830 can with time to spare.

Comment: @whatsisname: My Edge 820 only lasts for 4 hours or so (my smartphone actually has a better runtime with screen at full brightness and Osmand running), has the next generation really improved that much?

Comment: @mattnz there are good apps, ranging from really simple to highly configurable (more easily configurable than a Garmin too).  On the road they work really well.A bigger issue is that getting decent battery life on a phone is tricky

Comment: Unless you want to add annoying blaring speakers, amp and battery (weight!) to your bike you'd have to listen to music through earbuds which is illegal in many countries.

Comment: @Michael i'd suggest maybe your 820 has a faulty/degraded battery if its only lasting 4hrs.  My 800/810 both last 10-12hrs even after many years of abuse.

Comment: @AndyP: Looked it up, [this BikeRadar review](https://www.bikeradar.com/reviews/training/gps-computers/garmin-edge-830-gps-computer-review/) says 8h for the 830, 4h for the 820. I’m not even using navigation, Wifi, or a connected Smartphone. Only my power meter and BLE connected lights.

Comment: If the BikeRadar review is to be trusted, they didn't bother to try how long it actually takes. The battery gauges are not always reliable. Also, there are other brands out there, why are you so fixated on Garmin?

Comment: @ojs: Garmin is the market leader. I think it’s a fair warning considering how far from reality their official battery runtime specs are. I can say for certain that the 4h runtime on the 820 matches my experience. In summer it’s maybe 5h. Granted, the battery is 2 or 3 years old by now, but for some people that’s not enough runtime to last even a single training session. For me it makes the Edge 820 unusable for navigation while traveling (there are other issues with navigation too).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done via a workaround on the Hammerhead Karoo, which is fundamentally an Android device with a cycling app.

You can use a process known as 'side loading' to install other android apps on it (I have no idea what impact this has on the warranty).

To get music, users have successfully installed Spotify on their Karoo.

[DC Rainmaker](https://www.dcrainmaker.com/2021/02/how-to-sideload-android-apps-on-your-hammerhead-karoo-1-karoo-2.html) provides a step by step guide on the process of side loading an app.